# SARIMA Models How to know if my D is 0, or no?

Tags: time-series, arima, econometrics, eviews

In ARIMA model i know if my d is different of 0 if the time series is not stationary. But in SARIMA model how could i know if my D is different of 0?

Comment: Integration is *one* possibility for nonstationarity. There are others. See the duplicate for the OCSB test, which is used by what I consider the gold standard of auto-ARIMA tools.